# How does the cursor inside if statment can loop using IDBCursor.continue() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cursor, indexeddb

Using the example from the documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBCursor/continue):

```
function displayData() {
    var transaction = db.transaction(['rushAlbumList'], "readonly");
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore('rushAlbumList');

    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
        var cursor = event.target.result;
        if(cursor) {
            var listItem = document.createElement('li');
            listItem.innerHTML = cursor.value.albumTitle + ', ' + cursor.value.year;
            list.appendChild(listItem);

            cursor.continue();
        } else {
            console.log('Entries all displayed.');
        }
    };
};
```

It seems that the if statement is looping the cursor when the cursor detects that there are still data row stored in it using the method cursor.continue().

My question is, how is it looping?

Comment: `cursor.continue()` causes the event to fire again if there are more rows in the result set.

Comment: [`.continue()`](https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#dom-idbcursor-continue) -> 11. Run asynchronously execute a request with this's source, operation, and request -> [5.6. Asynchronously executing a request](https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#async-execute-request) -> 6. Queue a task -> 4.3 Fire a success event at request. -> and we're back at `var cursor = event.target.result; ...`

Comment: @Barmar oh so i see, so the .onsuccess kinda like looping itself. iteresting.

Comment: That's correct. It's similar to a `setTimeout()` function calling `setTimeout()` again.

Comment: @Andreas yes, the call stack. thanks for that.

Comment: @Barmar  yes recursive setTimeout but with limitation. yes thank you now i get it.